# Datagridview Textbox Not keeping time from DateTime.Now

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using the following code to set the value of a textbox in a datagridview. The code does exactly what I want. However when I leave the current row, the value in CloseDate maintains the current date but discards the time and changes to "00:00:00".

The underlying SQL field is set to datetime. The DataType in the underlying data source is system.DateTime, DateTimeMode is set to UnspecifiedLocal.

What am I missing?

```
tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CloseDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
```

From the EditingControlShowing action of my datagridview, I'm looking to see which field is being changed. In this instance I want 6.

```
private void tbl_TransactionsDataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combo != null && tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            // Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid  
            // adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged -=
                new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

            // Add the event handler. 
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged +=
                new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }

        if (combo != null && tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6)
        {
            // Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid  
            // adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged -=
                new EventHandler(Status_SelectedIndexChanged);

            // Add the event handler. 
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged +=
                new EventHandler(Status_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
    }
```

When the column index is 6, the following gets fired (I'm having some difficulties with getting this to fire correctly all the time, but thats an issue for another thread.). When it fires, it fires correctly and while I stay in the current row, CloseDate has the value I want it to. However, if I go to a new row and create a new record or select another record in the datagridview, CloseDate changes from "8/18/2014 8:42:32" to "8/18/2014 00:00:00".

```
private void Status_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object oStatus = new object();
            oStatus = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue;
            if (Convert.IsDBNull(oStatus) && Convert.ToInt32(oStatus) == 1)
            {
                tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CheckOutEmployee"].Value = Environment.UserName;
                tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CheckInEmployee"].Value = null;
                tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CloseDate"].Value = null;
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }

            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(oStatus) && Convert.ToInt32(oStatus) > 1)
            {
                tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CheckInEmployee"].Value = Environment.UserName;
                tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CloseDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you said "when I leave the current row", What dataGridView event are you using to enter an to pass the DateTime.Now value to the dataGridView cell?

Comment: I edited my original post to give more information.